# Matlab forming equation

Tags: matlab, math, matlab-deployment

I have problem with writing this equation into Matlab. Somehow just can't get it right. Could someone help me with it?

[image: Formula to be converted into Matlab]

Comment: It would be more convincing if you showed the least bit of signs of trying to solve it.

Comment: I'm guessing this is a joke right?

Comment: Yeah I'm not touching this one.

Comment: I found a really nice closed form expression of that integral, but the proof is too large to fit the margin here.

Answer (score 1):

You can take the summation outside the integral, and define that ugly prefactor as a new variable:

```
i=0;
sum=0;
while true
   i=i+1;
%{
   fac=(2^i*u/W-1)^(2/alpha)
   sum=sum+int(1/(1+fac)/int([1/(1+x^alpha/2), 1/fac,1.0/0])...
           /(lambda*A)^i*factorial(i)*e^(-lambda*A-K*rho*A)...
           *rho^K*K^K/gamma(K)*A^{K-1},0,1.0/0);
%}
end
```

and then check `sum>=1-eta`.

Note that I shifted the summation by 1 for convenience, as it's better to index everything from 1 in matlab.

Comment: Is that `fac = (...)^2/alpha` or `(...)^(2/alpha)` ... ?

Comment: @WhiteViking Thanks, edited.

Comment: I think the same goes for `1+x^alpha/2` -> `1+x^(alpha/2)`. Sorry :-)